# How to declare a cursor after the begin section of an Oracle PL/SQL procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am new in Oracle PL/SQL. I trying to write a procedure where I would first get data from a column in a table and assign to a variable. Then for each row/value in the result, I perform another query and loop through the result of this new query and perform various inserts and updates. After which I would go back to the outer loop and continue the sequence. My attempt is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CMSADMIN.Proc_RFC_UPD_NEW_MRSP
IS

    ecode NUMBER;
    emesg VARCHAR2(200);

    cursor y IS (select distinct cod_unicom FCODE from RFC_UPD_NEW_MRSP_POOL);

BEGIN

for t in y loop 

    cursor X IS ( 
                SELECT DISTINCT s.NIF PREMISE,a.COD_UNICOM READING, A.COD_LECT_AREA AREA
                FROM SUMCON s, LECT_AREAS a 
                WHERE a.COD_UNICOM  = t.FCODE
                AND s.NUM_SUM IN (select num_sum from RFC_UPD_NEW_MRSP_POOL where cod_unicom = t.FCODE)
                ); 


        for met in x loop 

            /* Store record trace*/
            INSERT into RFC_UPD_NEW_MRSP(NIF, COD_UNICOM,COD_LECT_AREA, USUARIO, F_ACTUAL, PROGRAMA) 
            values (met.PREMISE, met.READING, met.AREA, USER, SYSDATE,'RFC_MRSP_FPL'); 

            UPDATE  fincas_per_lect fp
            SET 
             FP.NUM_MRSP = MET.READING,
             fp.AOL_FIN=0,
             fp.NUM_ITIN =0,
             fp.USUARIO = user, fp.PROGRAMA = 'RFC_MRSP_FPL', fp.F_ACTUAL = sysdate
             WHERE Fp.NIF=met.PREMISE;

            UPDATE   apmedida_ap  fp
            SET 
             FP.NUM_MRSP = MET.READING,
             fp.USUARIO = user, fp.PROGRAMA = 'RFC_MRSP_FPL', fp.F_ACTUAL = sysdate

              WHERE Fp.NIF_apa = met.PREMISE;

            UPDATE FINCAS fp 
             SET AREA_LECT = MET.AREA,
                fp.USUARIO = user, fp.PROGRAMA = 'RFC_MRSP_FPL', fp.F_ACTUAL = sysdate
                WHERE NIF = met.PREMISE;

        end loop;

end loop;

    COMMIT;
    dbms_output.put_line('The procedure Proc_RFC_UPD_NEW_MRSP executed successfully');

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ecode := SQLCODE;
        emesg := SQLERRM;
        dbms_output.put_line('The procedure Proc_RFC_UPD_NEW_MRSP fail with folowing error '|| TO_CHAR(ecode) || ' and error message: ' || emesg);
        NULL;
end Proc_RFC_UPD_NEW_MRSP;
```

As you can see I have another cursor after the for loop inside `BEGIN`. Is this allowed? The script doesn't work as expected. What could be the problem? Appreciate any help

Comment: Avoid nested loops for updates. In most cases you can use join instead of nested pl_sql loops. Also consider bulk/forall.

Comment: Why not replace sql in x cursor with inner join? you have distinct so inner join will not change number of returned rows but will perform better.

Comment: Do you really name your variables `x`, `y` and `t`? I use `i` and `r` for numeric and cursor loops respectively (unless I need to nest things as in your example - but I would try very hard to avoid that), otherwise I always use a meaningful name, as random letters are pretty confusing.

Comment: btw capturing `sqlcode` is unneccessary, as it's just the numeric portion of `sqlerrm`, e.g. if sqlerrm is `ORA-01426: numeric overflow` then sqlcode is `-1426`. It doesn't add anything to the message. And you should really re-raise the exception, otherwise the procedure will just appear to succeed even if it only did some of the steps it should have done.

Comment: Hi @WilliamRobertson, How do I re-raise the exception as you suggested?

Comment: [`RAISE;`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/raise_statement.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you'd need to declare a new block:

```
for t in y loop 
    DECLARE
    cursor X IS ( 
                SELECT DISTINCT s.NIF PREMISE,a.COD_UNICOM READING, A.COD_LECT_AREA AREA
                FROM SUMCON s, LECT_AREAS a 
                WHERE a.COD_UNICOM  = t.FCODE
                AND s.NUM_SUM IN (select num_sum from RFC_UPD_NEW_MRSP_POOL where cod_unicom = t.FCODE)
                ); 
     BEGIN

        for met in x loop 
...
        end loop;
     END;
```

However, I don't quite see why you can't just declare this cursor along with cursor y, defined with a parameter:

```
cursor X (p_FCODE RFC_UPD_NEW_MRSP_POOL.cod_unicom%TYPE) IS ( 
            SELECT DISTINCT s.NIF PREMISE,a.COD_UNICOM READING, A.COD_LECT_AREA AREA
            FROM SUMCON s, LECT_AREAS a 
            WHERE a.COD_UNICOM  = p_FCODE
            AND s.NUM_SUM IN (select num_sum from RFC_UPD_NEW_MRSP_POOL where cod_unicom = p_FCODE)
            );
```

You could then reference the cursor thusly:

```
FOR met IN x(t.FCODE) LOOP
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your input. I am using `WHERE a.COD_UNICOM  = t.FCODE` so I can't declare along with cursor y

Comment: `t.FCODE` is a value obtain from the query perform in first cursor

Comment: It sounds like you are using cursor with input parameters - you can pass input values into cursor same way as into procedure and use them inside cursor as binds.

Comment: Hi DCookie and @Rusty you're awesome. Thanks for the contribution.

Comment: @DCookie I don't even think you need the parameter in the joined query - you could do a correlated subquery, like: `WHERE s.NUM_SUM IN (select num_sum from RFC_UPD_NEW_MRSP_POOL t where t.cod_unicom = a.COD_UNICOM)`.

Comment: @DCookie it should be `y.FCODE`

Comment: @FokwaBest no it shouldn't - you declared `t` to be the record that the `y` cursor fetches into, so when you want to reference values that have been fetched, you have to fetch them from the `t` record. So `t.fcode` is perfectly correct.

Comment: Hi @Boneist. You're right. thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
  cursor cur1 is 
  ...
begin
  ...

  declare
    cursor cur2 is
    ...
  begin
  end;
end;
```